# EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue when rendering WebP images using libwebp

Tags: ios, swift, webp

I'm trying to render WebP images in a UIImageView using the libwebp library in Swift. However, I'm encountering an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error with the following details:

> Thread 4: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x700008d57f38)

I have followed the documentation and implemented a custom solution for decoding WebP images using libwebp. Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:

```
import UIKit
import libwebp

extension UIImageView {
    func renderWebPImage(from url: URL) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            guard let webpData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
                return
            }
            
            // Decode the WebP image data using libwebp
            guard let image = webpDecode(webpData) else {
                return
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Create a UIImage from the decoded data and assign it to the UIImageView
                self.image = UIImage(cgImage: image)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func webpDecode(_ data: Data) -> CGImage? {
        // Decode the WebP image data using libwebp
        guard let webpDataPointer = data.withUnsafeBytes({ $0.baseAddress }),
              let webpDataLength = data.withUnsafeBytes({ $0.count }) as? Int else {
            return nil
        }
        
        // Create a WebPDecoderConfig object
        var config = WebPDecoderConfig()
        
        // Initialize the WebPDecoderConfig with default values
        WebPInitDecoderConfig(&config)
        
        // Decode the WebP image data and populate the WebPDecoderConfig object
        let result = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &config) { configPointer -> Int32 in
            return WebPDecode(webpDataPointer, webpDataLength, configPointer)
        }
        
        guard result == VP8_STATUS_OK,
              let image = config.output.u.RGBA.webpDecodedImage() else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return image
    }
}

extension WebPRGBABuffer {
    func webpDecodedImage() -> CGImage? {
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        
        guard let context = CGContext(
            data: self.rgba,
            width: Int(self.width),
            height: Int(self.height),
            bitsPerComponent: 8,
            bytesPerRow: Int(self.stride),
            space: colorSpace,
            bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue
        ) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        guard let cgImage = context.makeImage() else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return cgImage
    }
}

// Usage:
let imageView = UIImageView()
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/image.webp")!

imageView.renderWebPImage(from: URL)
```

I have ensured that the libwebp library is properly linked to my project and the WebP image file at the specified URL is valid. However, I'm still encountering the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

I suspect that the issue might be related to memory access or incorrect usage of the libwebp library. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error and successfully render WebP images using libwebp in Swift.
[image]

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: Also note that UIImage has native support for WebP as of iOS 14. You shouldn't need a 3rd party library.

Comment: Can you show me how I can use it on UIImage I could not find a native example/

Comment: You create the UIImage like any other. The code would be the same for PNG, JPEG, or WebP.

Comment: may be SDWebImage can help you, this is an extension on UIImageView and supports webp, https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage